# XercesDOMParser scoped instantiation causes segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, xerces-c

I have just come across a strange behavior of the Xerces-C library which I do not understand. The following code, which has already been seen in loads of examples, works for me:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace xercesc;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize ();
        XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser ();
        // here one might want to add some useful operations
        delete parser;
        XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate ();
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "caught some exception" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Surely, this code does not do many meaningful things. But it runs and in particular **terminates cleanly**.

Now, I was trying to avoid the `new/delete` and switch to a scoped object, like so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace xercesc;


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize ();
        XercesDOMParser parser;
        // here one might want to add some useful operations
        XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate ();
    }
    catch (XMLException& exc) {
        cout << "caught an XMLException" << endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "caught an exception" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This or similar code has also been seen many times. However, when I run it, it **creates a segfault** *after* (?) `XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()` (that's at least, what my debugger is suggesting). Still, I have successfully worked with a parser object created in that way. And if I omit the call to `Terminate()`, I see my process terminate cleanly.

Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: *Now, I was trying to avoid the new/delete and switch to a scoped object, like so:* -- The code does not do the same thing.  The second version has a live `parser` object when Terminate is called.  Also, `// here one might want to add some useful operations` -- are you actually doing anything?  If so, then you need to post this.

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for looking into this. No, I am not doing anything in the placeholders - the code is complete. Yes, I was also suspecting it might be the live parser object, but -funny enough- if I omit the `delete parser()` call in the first example, that one works nonetheless.

Comment: Well, xerces-c++ comes with full source code.  You could attempt to debug both scenarios to see what `Terminate` is actually doing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Paul, your first comment was correct indeed. Explicitly creating an inner scope leads to correct behavior. So obviously there are subtle differences in cleaning up between both variants. I am new on Stackoverflow. How can I give you credits for your hint? Can you re-post it as an answer so I can accept it? What is the best practice here?

Comment: @Midi So I guess you also tried something like this: `try {XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize ();  { XercesDOMParser parser; }  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate(); }` --  If that works correctly, then more than likely `Terminate()` makes any existing `XercesDOMParser` object that happen to be alive similar to a "dangling pointer".  In other words, any operation on a live parser object after `Terminate()` is "undefined behavior".  Not sure what else to make of it.

Answer (score 0):

Paul's comment already gave the correct answer and his explanation why does make sense. So for completeness, here is the code that actually works (note the explicitly created inner scope):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace xercesc;


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize ();
        {
            XercesDOMParser parser;
            // here one might want to add some useful operations
        }
        XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate ();
    }
    catch (XMLException& exc) {
        cout << "caught an XMLException" << endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "caught an exception" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you Paul!